# Does Pepper QISDK sync calls ensure a result?

Tags: android, kotlin, pepper

From the `QiSDK` docs it is understandable, that `async()` calls of `Future<T>` has result statuses.

e.x.

```
var goto = GoToBuilder..
var operation = goto.async().run().thenConsume {    
//if(it.isSuccess or it.hasError()) etc. statuses are available
}
//These statuses are also available in the $operation variable afterwards
if(operation.hasError()) {...}
```

But when we call operations `sync()`

e.x. just

```
var goto = GoToBuilder...
goto.run()
```

Does it **ensures that the operation will be completed with the success**?

Will it also lock the `current Thread` or what should we know about `sync()` calls? Because the docs say, that the best practice is to always use `async()`, but what if I don't want Pepper to create a `new Thread` for an action and process them alongside with the code.

Comment: sync() - it will wait for the tasks to be completed. then execute the other tasks.  async() - it will not wait for the task to be completed. it executes the other tasks parallel, but it has the callbacks for success and error. You can refer this link, https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-qisdk/principles/synchronous-or-asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it ensures that the operation will be completed with the success?

No, using `async()` or not has no effect on chances of success; what changes is that if an error occurs:

- With `.async()`, the future will finish with an error (`.hasError()`, `.getErrorMessage()` ...)
- With a sync call, the call will raise an exception (so you can wrap it with a try / catch)

> Will it also lock the current Thread or what should we know about sync() calls?

Yes, a sync call will block the current thread until the action is finished (succeeds, is cancelled or fails), which means you should never do that in the android main thread (the UI thread), or you will get a `NetworkOnUIThread` exception.

Note that not all calls finish on their own; for example `chat.run()` on a `Chat` object will run "forever", that is, until it's cancelled or an error is raised. That's another case where `.sync()` is useful, because you will get a future that you can cancel in order to stop the chat.